# Match repeatable string as a "whole word" in Lua 5.1

Tags: regex, lua, lua-5.1, lpeg

My environment:

- Lua 5.1
- Absolutely no libraries with a native component (like a C .so/.dll) can be used
- I can run any arbitrary pure Lua 5.1 code, but I can't access `os` and several other packages that would allow access to the native filesystem, shell commands or anything like that, so all functionality must be implemented in Lua itself (only).
- I've already managed to pull in [LuLpeg](https://github.com/pygy/LuLPeg). I can probably pull in other pure Lua libraries.

I need to write a function that returns `true` if the input string matches an arbitrary sequence of letters and numbers as a *whole word* that repeats one or more times, and may have punctuation at the beginning or end of the entire matching substring. I use "whole word" in the same sense as the PCRE word boundary `\b`.

To demonstrate the idea, here's an incorrect attempt using the `re` module of LuLpeg; it seems to work with negative lookaheads but not negative look*behinds*:

```lua
function containsRepeatingWholeWord(input, word)
    return re.match(input:gsub('[%a%p]+', ' %1 '), '%s*[^%s]^0{"' .. word .. '"}+[^%s]^0%s*') ~= nil
end
```

Here are example strings and the expected return value (the quotes are syntactical as if typed into the Lua interpreter, not literal parts of the string; this is done to make trailing/leading spaces obvious):

- **input:** `" one !tvtvtv! two"`, **word:** `tv`, **return value:** `true`
- **input:** `"I'd"`, **word:** `d`, **return value:** `false`
- **input:** `"tv"`, **word:** `tv`, **return value:** `true`
- **input:** `"   tvtv!  "`, **word:** `tv`, **return value:** `true`
- **input:** `" epon "`, **word:** `nope`, **return value:** `false`
- **input:** `" eponnope "`, **word:** `nope`, **return value:** `false`
- **input:** `"atv"`, **word:** `tv`, **return value:** `false`

If I had a full PCRE regex library I could do this quickly, but I don't because I can't link to C, and I haven't found any pure Lua implementations of PCRE or similar.

I'm not certain if LPEG is flexible enough (using LPEG directly or through its `re` module) to do what I want, but I'm pretty sure the built-in Lua functions can't do what I want, because it can't handle repeating sequences of characters. `(tv)+` does not work with Lua's builtin `string:match` function and similar.

Interesting resources I've been scouring to try to figure out how to do this, to no avail:

- http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/re.html
- http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1
- http://lua-users.org/wiki/FrontierPattern (unfortunately not supported in my interpreter)
- http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial
- http://www.gammon.com.au/lpeg
- http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringRecipes
- [how to check if a word appears as a whole word in a string in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852605/how-to-check-if-a-word-appears-as-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-lua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua patterns are powerful enough.
No LPEG is needed here.

This is your function

```
function f(input, word)
   return (" "..input:gsub(word:gsub("%%", "%%%%"), "\0").." "):find"%s%p*%z+%p*%s" ~= nil
end
```

This is a test of the function

```
for _, t in ipairs{
   {input = " one !tvtvtv! two", word = "tv", return_value = true},
   {input = "I'd", word = "d", return_value = false},
   {input = "tv", word = "tv", return_value = true},
   {input = "   tvtv!  ", word = "tv", return_value = true},
   {input = " epon ", word = "nope", return_value = false},
   {input = " eponnope ", word = "nope", return_value = false},
   {input = "atv", word = "tv", return_value = false},
} do
   assert(f(t.input, t.word) == t.return_value)
end
```

Comment: This taught me a lot about what Lua's built-in regexps can do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think the pattern doesn't work reliably because the `%s*[^%s]^0` part matches an optional series of spacing characters followed by non-spacing characters, and then it tries to match the reduplicated word and fails. After that, it doesn't go backwards or forwards in the string and try to match the reduplicated word at another position. The semantics of LPeg and `re` are very different from those of most regular expression engines, even for things that look similar.

Here's a `re`-based version. The pattern has a single capture (the reduplicated word), so if the reduplicated word was found, matching returns a string rather than a number.

```
function f(str, word)
    local patt = re.compile([[
        match_global <- repeated / ( [%s%p] repeated / . )+
        repeated <- { %word+ } (&[%s%p] / !.) ]],
        { word = word })
    return type(patt:match(str)) == 'string'
end
```

It is somewhat complex because the vanilla `re` does not have a way to generate a `lpeg.B` pattern.

Here's a `lpeg` version using `lpeg.B`. LuLPeg also works here.

```
local lpeg = require 'lpeg'
lpeg.locale(lpeg)

local function is_at_beginning(_, pos)
    return pos == 1
end

function find_reduplicated_word(str, word)
    local type, _ENV = type, math
    local B, C, Cmt, P, V = lpeg.B, lpeg.C, lpeg.Cmt, lpeg.P, lpeg.V
    local non_word = lpeg.space + lpeg.punct
    local patt = P {
        (V 'repeated' + 1)^1,
        repeated = (B(non_word) + Cmt(true, is_at_beginning))
                * C(P(word)^1)
                * #(non_word + P(-1))
    }
    return type(patt:match(str)) == 'string'
end

for _, test in ipairs {
    { 'tvtv', true },
    { ' tvtv', true },
    { ' !tv', true },
    { 'atv', false },
    { 'tva', false },
    { 'gun tv', true },
    { '!tv', true },
} do
    local str, expected = table.unpack(test)
    local result = find_reduplicated_word(str, 'tv')
    if result ~= expected then
        print(result)
        print(('"%s" should%s match but did%s')
            :format(str, expected and "" or "n't", expected and "n't" or ""))
    end
end
```

Comment: This is excellent documentation of what `lpeg.re` and `lpeg` can do, but since in my case LPEG is interpreted Lua code and `string` is native C code as part of the Lua runtime, Egor's solution is faster. I guess, I would only use LuLPeg in my environment, if the built-in `string` functions couldn't do what I needed. But I've upvoted and this definitely helped me understand LPeg better for future needs.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine the `string` library-based solution will be much faster and more memory-efficient that LuLPeg.